# Titan Retrieving Vertex Properties

Tags: titan, tinkerpop3

I am creating a graph in a highly multithreaded environment and I am encountering a strange error. Whilst running I sometimes get an error that the property I am trying to access does not exist.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The property does not exist as it has no key, value, or associated element
```

To try and figure this out I put a break point when that error occurred and found some strange behaviour.

When I run :

```
Vertex vertex = graph.traversal().V(123).next();
vertex.properties();
```

I see the list of all the properties I am expecting, for example `"PROP1"`, `"PROP2"`, and `"PROP3"`. However when I run the following:

```
vertex.property("PROP1").value();
```

I get an error that the property does not exist. Even more strange is that `vertex.property(xxx).value();` works for the other properties `"PROP2"` and `"PROP3"`. What can lead to this strange behaviour ?

Answer (score 2):

As a good practice, you should always check before you hit `next()`

For example,

```
traversal=graph.traversal().V(123);
if (traversal.hasNext()) // avoid fast no property exception here.
    vertex=traversal.next()
```

Another thing, `vertex.property("PROP1")` might be a bit strange to retrieve a value. `property()` retrieves the property object and that's not what you want I assume, if it doesn't find it, it throws an exception. Instead, a better way to get a value would be through `vertex.values("PROP1")`. This will return null if property doesn't exist.

Check documentations [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and good advice but this does not resolve the underlaying issue. Using `values()` instead of `property()` also throws the exception. The underlaying issue is that when I list all of the property keys I see everything that I expect. i.e. `"PROP1"` to `PROPN` but when I request the value with either `vertex.value("PROP1")` or `vertex("PROP1")` I get the missing property exception.

Furthermore when using just `vertex.values()` I see all the values that I am expecting. I.e what should be returned by `vertex.value("PROP1")`